# Fix msysGit Portable $HOME location

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit, portable-applications, home-directory

I have successfully installed and configured msysGit Portable on my flash drive, and have used it to pull and push GitHub repos. However, I seem to always have to kludge the SSH support.

Specifically, in order for SSH to find my key files, I have to follow [these instructions](http://chickenandbeans.vox.com/library/post/weird-ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent.html) to start a second instance of `ssh-agent` and then `ssh-add` my key every time I run git-bash.bat.

Using the output of `ssh -v git@github.com` to debug I see that msysGit defaults to my Windows user directory to look for keys. It can't do that; I need it to look in its own directory on the portable drive.

How can I force $HOME to be the program's own folder?

#### Update for broken Vox link

Instructions from [this page](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/Facilities/FAQ/Security/openssh.html) are similar to the now-broken link I originally posted. Quoted below. Also here's the [webarchive of original Vox article](http://web.archive.org/web/20100323030730/http://chickenandbeans.vox.com/library/post/weird-ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent.html).

> However, if you try this and get:
>
> ```
> % ssh-add
> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
> ```
>
> then your session is not running under the ssh-agent. You can get around this by restarting a new shell under the agent by running:
>
> ```
> exec ssh-agent bash
> ```
>
> where you can replace bash with the shell of your choice. Once you do this, you should be able to run ssh-add to load your key for that shell.

Comment: As a byproduct of a solution to this problem, I'm hoping that all the other files that end up scattered through the user directory of whatever PC I'm using will be properly located as well. .bash_history, .gitk, etc. should travel with me, not be left behind every time I switch machines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19136789/1233435 has some helpful details on the `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command used to launch git bash is:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Prog\Git\1.7.1\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
```

I just tried the following in a DOS session:

```
C:\>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Prog\Git\1.7.1\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
VonC@XXX /c/
$ echo $HOME
/c/Users/VonC
```

By default, $HOME$%HOMEPATH%, but if I force %HOME%:

```
set HOME=/another/path
```

and then launch the same bash session:

```
C:\>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Prog\Git\1.7.1\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
VonC@XXX /c/
$ echo $HOME
/another/path
```

So if you wrap the bash call by a script setting the HOME to:

- `%~dp0` : the path of the wrapper on your USB key
- or `%~d1\your\path`: with `%~d1` being the drive letter (of your usb key if your wrapper is on it)

, you should be able to force HOME to whatever value you need.

---

Note (November 2011): since then, the [OP dgw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5991/dgw) has written his [own wrapper](https://gist.github.com/533267):

`git-bash-portable.bat`:

```
@echo off
rem Copyright (C): 2010 Voyagerfan5761
rem http://technobabbl.es/

set USERPROFILE=%~dp0
set HOMEDRIVE=%~d0
set HOMEPATH=%~p0
set HOME=%~dp0
set HISTFILE=%USERPROFILE%.bash_history
rem set BASHRC=%USERPROFILE%.bashrc

git-bash.bat
```

The article "[Portable Git for Windows: setting the `$HOME` environment variable to allow complete portability (including SSL keys and configuration for use with GitHub)](http://markashleybell.com/portable-git-windows-setting-home-environment-variable.html)" also add useful information.

> However, if you install Git on a portable drive, you'll want your settings to travel with the installation—which obviously they won't if it is looking for them in a folder which may not exist on other computers.
>
> So, what we need to do is tell Portable Git to treat a specific location within its own folder as the home folder; that way we can copy the whole Git folder anywhere we like and the settings will travel with it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try this out as soon as I can (on the road right now, but I'll have time at some point) and will accept your answer once I verify that it'll work. (I'd accept now, but it seems odd to accept an answer before verifying its correctness.)

Comment: @Voyager: no problem, take your time ;) I have had answer accepted after a long (very long) time before :) See the comments of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36318/whats-the-longest-interval-between-an-answer-being-posted-and-accepted

Comment: Great thread. :) I've just tested my wrapper and it totally worked like a charm. Only detail left is whether I can get the value of `%~dp0` without the trailing slashes; any ideas? If not, that's fine; my setup is still working great.

Comment: @Voyager: if you use a fixed path (always the same) in your USB, you ould use just `%d1` and build your path as you see fit. If not, you need to remove the last char, with DOS-based character substitution. See http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php. `set str=%str:-1%` should do it.

Comment: Any ideas why this isn't the default behavior for the portable installer?  It's extremely frustrating to figure this out, and I'm pretty sure I'm going to mess it up and require my user to have to mess with this on every computer he uses (ie, he won't use it as a result of this behavior).

Comment: I think it's just that the developer of the portable package can't be bothered to implement this. I asked, and was told it wouldn't be added. But [here](http://markashleybell.com/articles/portable-git-windows-setting-home-environment-variable) is another solution (tip: read the comments); try out that and [my BAT file](https://gist.github.com/533267) to see what works best for you.

Comment: how about for the non-portable version?

Comment: @Severus you can write your own `git-cmd.bat` which will re-define `HOME` and call git.

Answer (score 1):

### Setting the home dir

The solution with a `git-bash-portable.bat` wrapper opens another Windows CMD window for me that stays in the background.

Another, more native solution is to adjust `/etc/profile` and set the HOME var there. Just add the following lines to the end of `/etc/profile`, `myuser` beeing your *virtual* username:

```
# end of /etc/profile
export HOME="/home/myuser"
cd
```

This sets the proper HOME directory and cds into it. Then the startup mechanism, like loading all files from `/etc/profile.d` works correctly and you just start `git-bash.exe` with a doubleclick.

Of course you have to create your home directory for this to work. Start git-bash and create it:

```
mkdir -p /home/myuser
```

### Starting or reconnecting to the agent

Regarding the agent, it usually has to be reloaded with every git-bash shell opened. A solution to get an independent agent spanning all git-bash windows is to include the following little script `~/.mgssh` in the startup. It stores the agent env vars in a file `agent.env` in the `.ssh` directory. Any new shell reads the file, checks if the agent is still running and connects to it. If it is not running it starts the agent and rewrites the `agent.env` file. Make sure your `.ssh` dir exists.

```
# cat ~/.mgssh

agentfile=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env()
{
  test -f "$agentfile" && . "$agentfile" >| /dev/null;
}

agent_start()
{
  (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$agentfile")
  . "$agentfile" >| /dev/null;
}

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
fi

# uncomment this, if you want to add a key on agent startup
#if [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
#    ssh-add
#fi

unset agentfile
```

Now source the `.mgssh` script in your `.bashrc`:

```
# cat .bashrc
. ~/.mgssh

# ... more .bashrc content
```

Found this on GitHub:

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/#platform-windows

### Killing the agent before stick removal

Usually, before you remove your usbstick you ask Windows to *eject* the stick, by right clicking it in the explorer or using the little systray icon. This will not work, if your agent is still up and running. Make sure to kill the agent before closing the last shell upon stick removal:

```
$ ssh-agent -k

unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 8472 killed;
```

Remark: Usually you would use `eval $(ssh-agent -k)` to unset the env vars as well, but as you do this just before closing the shell it's irrelevant. The above startup script `.mgssh` takes care of cleaning up the `~/.ssh/agent.env` file so that does not have to be done either.

Comment: Interesting approach. +1

Comment: Thanks for the +1. I corrected the $USERNAME to a hardcoded user matching the user dir in the home dir - different windows machines probably have different users so $USERNAME does not work. I also added instructions to kill the agent before stick removal.