# MSysGit and ssh config. missing

Tags: windows, git, ssh, msysgit

1) Run Git Bash (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe --login)

```
$ ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Alexander Fedorov/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
Hi xpoft! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
...
```

Okay! ssh config reading well.

2) Run from cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\Alexander Fedorov>ssh.exe -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
...
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Nooo. ssh config file is missing...

How... how read config from ssh.exe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is probably missing is the user environment variable `HOME`.

If you launch your DOS session from the `git-cmd.bat` script packaged with msysgit, it should be defined, and you should see `%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`

But from any other DOS windows, `HOME` isn't defined by default (`HOMEPATH` or `USERPROFILE` are).
See also "[Fix msysGit Portable $HOME location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454774/fix-msysgit-portable-home-location/3455231#3455231)" as an illustration (but you shouldn't need that workaround with recent versions of msysgit and its  `git-cmd.bat` script)

Comment: Ok! Thx. Add environment variable HOME