# Git Push origin Master Hangs - cygwin w/ windows 7

Tags: windows-7, github, cygwin, push

Pushing my first_app to git hub using cygwin on a windows 7 machine.  Using the command git push origin master I get no response.  Seems like it hangs and I have to ctrl c.  I have already added my ssh key to github...  Thanks.

Comment: Best to use msysgit (but make sure to set the variable HOME: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122439/msysgit-and-ssh-config-missing/10122865#10122865), or their own GitHub tool: http://windows.github.com/

Comment: Excellent. I have added an answer below making that option (msysgit instead of cygwin) clearer.

Comment: Wait, so is the only option to do this to use the msysgit provided bash window? I love my cygwin :( I don't use my ssh keys to commit to github, just password. Could swear this worked perfectly yesterday, but now it decided to hang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using msysgit or GitHub for Windows (which includes msysgit) is a safer choice.

It  will access your key at `HOME`, which will be by default under `%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%` unless you define HOME explicitly: see "[MSysGit and ssh config. missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122439/msysgit-and-ssh-config-missing/10122865#10122865)" for more.