# GitHub: Multiple account setup

Tags: github

I am trying since more than 3 hours to setting up multiple account for github and litteraly tired. I have tried out almost all possible way describe here, github and articles and none of them worked. I am completely newbie to github and Unix as well. So need your help to fix this. Here below what I am doing

I am using Windows 7 and have set two ssh key for two different accounts.

1. id_rsa
2. id_rsa_ac2

Than created config file in `.ssh` directory of the User and added below code

```
#Account one
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /c/Projects/.ssh/id_rsa

#Account two
Host ac2.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /c/Projects/.ssh/id_rsa_ac2
```

Now I am trying to add remote by using below code

```
git remote add origin git@ac2.github.com:myaccount/my.git
```

and push with bellow code

```
git push origin master
```

But when I am trying to push it is giving me Error:
`Error: Permission to myaccount/my.git denied to {account}. // where it is considering default user account and not for ac2 user account`
`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

`Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Thanks a lot..

**Additional Info:**

I have test the `id_rsa_ac2` and giving successfully authenticated message. But the strange thing is giving username with original account not with the `ac2` account username

`Hi {username!} You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. //here user id should be from ac2 but it is showing userid from id_rsa and not from id_rsa_ac2`

## INFORMATION: Final Code

@VonC's answer worked and adding final code as my answer if anyone want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your config to be taken into account, you need to use its `Host` name in your remote address:

```
git remote add origin ac2.github.com:myaccount/my
```

If you have defined a `HOME` environment variable (which isn't defined by default on Windows, but is defined if you are using the [msysgit `git-cmd.bat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10122865/6309)) to a directory under which you have your .ssh directory, with its `id_rsa_ac2` private key, and `id_rsa_ac2.pub` public key, then it will work.

Comment: Great help! it's done and working both account. Just for knowledge I have to use your both answers where you described to define `User git` than it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @VonC I left another answer with a script to automate everything. ( although the process is a bit different it works for GitLab, and I would assume GitHub as well.) let me know if you think I should add anything

Comment: @CodeLover 6 years later and my answer is not good enough? I agree, the other answers improve on it, but I still had answered your original question

Comment: @VonC it isn't about that but to make the answer selected which is more useful to other with detailed steps as well. Anyway, I have selected your answer once again.

Comment: @CodeLover Agreed: please do select the answer you think will help users. I was just surprised yesterday ;)

Comment: @VonC no problem :) It happens

Answer (score 4):

So according to @VonC's answer here what I have done.

1. I have generate ssh key for another account and added with
   id_rsa_ac2 (where ac2 is for second account)
2. Than just cross checked either it works with `ssh -T ac2.github.com`
3. Created **config** file (without extention) in
   /c/Users/yourname/.ssh/ directory

Here is the code what I used for config file

```
#Account one
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /c/Users/yourname/.ssh/id_rsa
    User git

#Account two
Host ac2.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /c/Users/yourname/.ssh/id_rsa_ac2
    User git
```

So now once you done this you can start to use both account as you need.

for main account I added remote as origin with `git remote add origin git@github/youraccount/rep.git`
Than to push use `git push origin master` this will upload to your first account.

To add remote for second (ac2) account used `git remote add ac2 ac2.github/yoursecondaccount/rep.git`
Than to push use `git push ac2 master` this will upload to the second (ac2) account.

To check if it has added remote use `git remote -v` and incase if you want to remove anyone than use `git remote rm origin` where origin is your added remote.

Hope this information will helps to other who is having the same issue.

Thanks again to @VonC

Comment: It's all because of you! Thanks again for your great help and appreciation :)

Comment: @CodeLover I left another answer with a script to automate everything.  ( although the process is a bit different it works for GitLab, and I would assume GitHub as well.) let me know if you think I should add anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script to Automate the addition of two GitLab Accounts to your setup.

[setup-gitlab.sh](https://gitlab.com/procyclinsur/Fedora-Environment/blob/master/Scripts/setup-gitlab.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

# VERIFIED FOR FEDORA 27 MATE (Likely to work in others distros)
# Multi Account SSH for GitLab/OpenSSH Setup.
ROOT=root
if (( whoami == $ROOT ))
    then 
    echo "Run as standard user"
elif [[ -z $1 || -z $2 ]]
    then
    echo "command usage: setup-gitlab.bash workemail@domain.com homeemail@domain.com"
elif [[ ! $1 =~ .*@.*\..* ]]
    echo "Work email is not in the correct format. Must match regex .*@.*\..*"
elif [[ ! $2 =~ .*@.*\..* ]]
    echo "Home email is not in the correct format. Must match regex .*@.*\..*"
else
    HOMEEMAIL=$1
    WORKEMAIL=$2
    USRNAME=`whomai`

# /home/<username>/.ssh/
# ├── config
# ├── home-gitlab-key
# ├── home-gitlab-key.pub
# ├── known_hosts
# ├── work-gitlab-key
# └── work-gitlab-key.pub

#Executed to match the above directory.
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$WORKEMAIL" -b 4096 -f work-gitlab -N ""
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$HOMEEMAIL" -b 4096 -f home-gitlab -N ""

# Agent Configuration Setup (.ssh/config)
    cat >> ~/.ssh/config <<EOF
Host gitlab-work
  HostName gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/$USRNAME/.ssh/work-gitlab-key

Host gitlab-home
  HostName gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/$USRNAME/.ssh/home-gitlab-key
EOF

# Agent Setup (potentially optional???)
    cat >> ~/.bashrc <<'EOF'
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
for i in `ls ~/.ssh/*.pub` ; do ssh-add ${i::-4} ; done
EOF

    . .bashrc

fi
```

After running the script you will need to copy the contents of the two public keys created to each GitLab account respectively.

Another note, when using `git clone git@gitlab.com:<account>/<project>.git` your should replace `gitlab.com` as follows.

```
git clone git@gitlab-home:<account>/<project>.git
```

and

```
git clone git@gitlab-work:<account>/<project>.git
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this script, that switch indentity and other all neccessary like git setting

https://gist.github.com/milosjanda/a86ebc039293f22fabe723024ec42b46

```
if [[ -f ~/.ssh/.work ]]; then
  echo "swith to HOME"
  # mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/work; mv ~/.ssh/home ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  rm ~/.ssh 2> /dev/null
  ln -s ~/.ssh-work/home ~/.ssh
  git config --global user.email "my.name@gmail.com"
else
  echo "swith to WORK"
  # mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/home; mv ~/.ssh/work ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  rm ~/.ssh 2> /dev/null
  ln -s ~/.ssh-work/work ~/.ssh
  git config --global user.email "my.name@company.eu"
fi

# Delete all identities from ssh-agent
ssh-add -D

# Add new identity to ssh-agent
ssh-add
```