# GitHub: invalid username or password

Tags: github

I have a project hosted on GitHub. I fail when trying to push my modifications on the master. I always get the following error message

```
Password for 'https://git@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git@github.com/eurydyce/MDANSE.git/'
```

However, setting my ssh key to github seems ok. Indeed, when I do a `ssh -T git@github.com` I get

```
Hi eurydyce! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Which seems to indicate that everything is OK from that side (eurydyce being my github username). I strictly followed the instructions given on github and the recommendations of many stack discussion but no way. Would you have any idea of what I may have done wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I should post an answer or not(high chance get downvote), since I solved this error message by changed the password in github settings after tried many attempts with the "correct"(check by inspect element) password.

Comment: Some organizations have SAML SSO enabled. In this case, best is to use personal access token. If you are already logged in, please re-login and give Github Desktop/Sourcetree permission

Answer (score 419, accepted):

https://git@github.com/eurydyce/MDANSE.git is not an ssh url, it is an https one (which would require your GitHub account name, instead of '`git`').

Try to use `ssh://git@github.com:eurydyce/MDANSE.git` or just `git@github.com:eurydyce/MDANSE.git`

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:eurydyce/MDANSE.git
```

The [OP Pellegrini Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406014/pellegrini-eric) adds:

> That's what I did in my `~/.gitconfig` file that contains currently the following entries `[remote "origin"] url=git@github.com:eurydyce/MDANSE.git`

This should not be in your global config (the one in `~/`).
You could check `git config -l` in your repo: that url should be declared in the *local* config: `<yourrepo>/.git/config`.

So make sure you are in the repo path when doing the `git remote set-url` command.

---

As noted in [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101662/oliver)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919582/6309), an HTTPS URL would not use username/password if [two-factor authentication (2FA)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa) is activated.

In that case, the password should be a [PAT (personal access token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication#using-two-factor-authentication-with-the-command-line) as seen in "[Using a token on the command line](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line#using-a-token-on-the-command-line)".

That applies only for HTTPS URLS, SSH is not affected by this limitation.

Comment: oups ! You are right, making those changes in my local config made everything work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't understand this answer at all

Comment: @Clo sure, what part is lacking clarity, how may I improve this answer?

Comment: When I did this (replacing the username and repo name with mine), I get "Permission denied (publickey)." I would like to log in with username and password if possible.

Comment: @AaronFranke username/password means HTTPS URL, not SSH one.

Comment: I had to remove the git@ part to get this to work... so github.com:organization/repo.git

Comment: @byronaltice If this is SSH, that means you have a `~/.ssh/config` or `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file, with a `github.com` entry in it.

Comment: @VonC yes I do, it's for my ssh key so I don't have to put in a password every time. I think this should be part of the answer for anyone who wants to use an ssh key, seems like a lot more people than me would not want to type in their password every time.

Comment: @byronaltice I agree, but the answer is about HTTPS URL, not SSH. For SSH and config, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681936/6309

Comment: After generating the access token, rewrite the same command and enter username and password, that's it.

Comment: WTF is MDANSE.git? It's not available anymore

Comment: @chillappreciator it is the name of the repository in the OP, in 2015. That repository might not be available 8 years later indeed.

Answer (score 1496):

After enabling Two Factor Authentication (2FA), you may see something like this when attempting to use `git clone`, `git fetch`, `git pull` or `git push`:

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': your_user_name
Password for 'https://your_user_name@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/your_user_name/repo_name.git/'
```

### Why this is happening

From the [GitHub Help documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/#when-youll-be-asked-for-a-personal-access-token-as-a-password):

> After 2FA is enabled you will need to enter a personal access token instead of a 2FA code and your GitHub password.
>
> ...
>
> For example, when you access a repository using Git on the command line using commands like `git clone`, `git fetch`, `git pull` or `git push` with HTTPS URLs, you must provide your GitHub username and your personal access token when prompted for a username and password. The command line prompt won't specify that you should enter your personal access token when it asks for your password.

### How to fix it

1. Generate a [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens). (Detailed guide on [Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/).)
2. Copy the Personal Access Token.
3. Re-attempt the command you were trying and use Personal Access Token in the place of your password.

Related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21374369/101662

Comment: Kudo's and upvotes; the new token generation is what i needed.  Also; the "Copy code" included additional (invalid) characters so I had to manually enter my .... 20[?] digit random key.

Comment: This was my issue, after adding 2 factor auth, which i suspected, however the documentation on this was lacking. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @BeauSmith: That's way more substantive an edit than we normally allow. You basically completely rewrote this answer. Please post that as *your own, separate answer* instead. Also see [What do you do if someone basically re-writes your whole answer?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348873)

Comment: Let's all please allow the decision to rollback or not to be decided by @Oliver here - there's a perfectly sound argument either way

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Thanks for the link to the discussion. I didn't intend to create any drama. Just want to make things better for everyone.

Comment: I used this to get access via GitBash after adding 2step to my account i couldn't push to master.  My question is will i need to create a new token every time i want to use this.  Isnt there a way of setting my machine up to be able to access Git without the twostep or prompt for the code?

Comment: Why github documentation doesn't mention this (token key required instead of password) when create new repository ?

Comment: GitHub should be more clear on this notice when users enable 2FA on their accounts. THIS IS A FATAL ERROR.

Comment: Make sure to give yourself appropriate permissions.  Not giving any hoping to get through this as fast as possible will result in a 403=)

Comment: I had to allow the token full "repo" permissions before I could push to a public GitHub repository. Allowing only the "access to public repositories" did not work.

Comment: Thanks for this - using my Personal Access Token rather than my GitHub password worked for me. Upvoted.

Comment: Confirming this using Personal Access Token instead of password in "password" section succeeds git commands. It's a one time procedure, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I had to enable 2FA in order to use GitHub Co-pilot, then I ran into the problems described above. 

This answer here is very useful.

Comment: Note: This solution worked for me in Git Bash but not in normal command promt.

Comment: this worked for me on normal command prompt as well, Thanks a lot that worked!

Comment: On a Mac you may need remove the existing password from the Keychain app. To do this, open Keychain and delete the "github.com Access Key for ..." entry. Then when you next `push` it will prompt for the password, and you can just paste the PAT.

Answer (score 145):

Solution steps for Windows users:

1. Control Panel
2. Credential Manager
3. Click Windows Credentials
4. In Generic  Credential section ,there would be git url, update username and password
5. Restart Git Bash and try for clone

Note:
If you didn't find git url in Generic Credential section then follow below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858690/7372432

Comment: I was having this problem with a company version of github (so using local username/password). This solution fixed it.

Comment: In new windowses, you can search for "Windows credentials" or similar in your language. It'll pop up a result and you can try this solution.

Comment: Perfect solution for on premises github, where companies obliges you to use https

Comment: I was following another thread to refresh the credentials, with no luck. You solution works perfectly

Comment: Same issue: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 84):

> If like me you just updated your password and ran `git push` to run into this issue, then there's a super easy fix.

For Mac users only. You need to delete your OSX Keychain access entries for GitHub. You can do it via terminal by running the following commands.

#### Deleting your credentials via the command line

Through the command line, you can use the credential helper directly to erase the keychain entry.

To do this, type the following command:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https

# [Now Press Return]
```

If it's successful, nothing will print out. To test that it works, try and clone a repository from GitHub or run your previous action again like in my case `git push`. If you are prompted for a password, the keychain entry was deleted.

Comment: For windows:
git credential-wincred erase
host=github.com
protocol=https

Comment: I encountered this problem on a BitBucket repo. This answer with `host=bitbucket.org` instead of GitHub fixed it for me.

Comment: I had changed my Github password after which git pull wasn't working for me. This worked for me.

Comment: That's the right answer in case someone get stuck after the last Github authentication update to enforce login with a username/token instead of username/password.

Comment: Great, this exactly what I need in order to replace expired token with new one. thank you.

Answer (score 46):

Instead of `git pull` also try `git pull origin master`

I changed password, and the first command gave error:

```
$ git pull
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for ...
```

After `git pull origin master`, it asked for password and seemed to update itself

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it and it works!

Answer (score 38):

When using the `https://` URL to connect to your remote repository, then Git will not use SSH as authentication but will instead try a basic authentication over HTTPS. Usually, you would just use the URL without a username, e.g. `https://github.com/username/repository.git`, and Git would then prompt you to enter both a username (your GitHub username) and your password.

If you use `https://something@github.com/username/repository.git`, then you have preset the username Git will use for authentication: `something`. Since you used `https://git@github.com`, Git will try to log in using the `git` username for which your password of course doesn’t work. So you will have to use *your* username instead.

The alternative is actually to use SSH for authentication. That way you will avoid having to type your password all the time; and since it already seems to work, that’s what you should be using.

To do that, you need to change your remote URL though, so Git knows that it needs to connect via SSH. The format is then this: `git@github.com:username/repository`. To update your URL use this command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repository
```

Comment: when trying your command I get the following message `warning: remote.origin.url has multiple values`. This may be due to the fact that I already have an remote tag in my ~/.gitconfig file which contains the value `[remote "origin"] url=git@github.com:eurydyce/MDANSE.git`.

Comment: I've been searching for hours already on why I couldn't push my changes, and this answer finally gives a perfect explanation and helped me fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 33):

**2FA is enabled and getting error remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for**

If you set 2FA is enabled in GitHub you will need to enter a personal access token instead of a 2FA code and your GitHub password.

**How to fix it**

1. https://github.com/settings/tokens generated token
2. Copy the Personal Access Token
3. Now enter Personal Access Token in the place of your password during git operation

Comment: This was it! Could you explain what's going on here? Would I need the token for any Github related use from nowon?

Comment: After this, then follow @Anil_Reddy's answer.

Answer (score 29):

just try to push it to your branch again. This will ask your username and password again, so you can feed in the changed password. So that your new password will be stored again in the cache.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote.  In my case my credentials had been updated, and the second `git push` prompted for the appropriate update, as this answer indicates.

Comment: Not sure, what you meant, it is not asking for new credentials executing `git push origin master`...

Comment: Nice! Same thing if you're trying to `git clone` something but it tells you your username/password are incorrect. If either have recently changed, just run `git clone <myprojecturl>` again and this time it will ask you to re-enter your username and password.

Comment: very strange. Why it fails the first time but not the second time. (Vscode extension does the work)

Answer (score 22):

**This is the answer.**

Set the github token:

https://github.com/settings/tokens

And then:

```
git remote set-url origin https://[token]@github.com/your_repository
```

Comment: This worked for me, however, after running `git remote -v` I noticed my repository was using HTTPS for fetch and push whereas I thought it was using SSH.  If you already have SSH auth working (test with `ssh -T git@github.com`), then you should just be able to set-url to the SSH one.  Easy way to find the SSH url is to go to your repository on GitHub.com and click on the green "Code" button's "SSH" tab and copy the link.  Then run the command in your repository: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:your-user-or-org/your-repo-name.git` (replace the last bit with your copied link).

Answer (score 17):

I have got the success using the following commands.

```
git config --unset-all credential.helper
git config --global --unset-all credential.helper
git config --system --unset-all credential.helper
```

Comment: After this, doing `git push origin master` in any repo you have should prompt you again for your username (same as before) and password (use the Personal Access Token here).

Answer (score 12):

I am getting this while cloning app from bitbucket:

```
Cloning into 'YourAppName'...
Password for 'https://youruser id': 
remote: Invalid username or password
```

I solved it. Here you need to create password for your userid

1. Click on Your profile and settings
       [image: Click on Your profile and settings]
2. Then Create app password choose your name password will generated ,paste that password to terminal
       [image: Create app password]

Answer (score 12):

That problem happens sometimes due to wrong password. Please check if you are linked with AD password (Active Directory Password) and you recently changed you AD password but still trying git command with old password or not.

**Update old AD password**

```
Control Panel > Credential Manager > Windows Credential > change github password with my new AD password
```

Answer (score 11):

I did:

```
$git pull origin master
```

Then it asked for the [Username] & [Password] and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: This worked for me. I've used fetch instead pull but anyway it doesn't matter. Cool!

Comment: Beginning August 13, 2021 this will not supported

Comment: Feel free to edit and add what works @ZEHINZ! haven't run into this issue for a while so I am not even sure what the updated command is!

Answer (score 11):

***Run Below command, and after than on every push and pull it will ask you to enter the username and password.***

```
  git config credential.helper ""
```

[image]

**now when you pull/push you will be asked for git credentials. weather you are running through command prompt or Intellij Git.**

Answer (score 10):

No need to rely on Generating a **Personal Access Token** and then trying and use **Personal Access Token** in the place of your password.

Quick fix is to set your remote URL to point to `ssh` not `https`.

Do this `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repository`

Answer (score 9):

If you have just enabled 2FA :

Modify hidden `config` file in `./git` hidden folder as follow :

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://username:PUT_YOUR_2FA_TOKEN_HERE@github.com/project/project.git
```

Comment: but what if the folder did not exist yet? I am unable to do even `git clone` of a private repo in github

Comment: Thank you. I spent more than two hours on this issue. Your answer saved my day

Comment: Me too. I wasn't prompted to reenter the new token. This was the only way to get it working.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
# git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repository
```

Answer (score 4):

Disabling 2 factor authentication at github worked for me.

I see that there is a deleted answer that says this, with the deletion reason as "does not answer the question".   If it works, then I think it answers the question...

Comment: This is weird. Same happened with me.
I just disabled two-factor authentication and it works now for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

You might be getting this error because you have updated your password. So on Terminal first make sure you clear your GitHub credentials from the keychain and then push your changes to your repo, terminal will ask for your username and password.

Answer (score 3):

In case you get this error message in this situation:

- using **github for entreprise**
- using **credential.helper=wincred** in git config
- using your **windows credentials** which you **changed** recently

Then look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/521257

Windows stores credentials in a credentials manager, clear it or update it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Control panel
2. Credential manager
3. Look for options webcredentials and windows credentials
4. in either one you will find github credentials fix it with correct credentials
5. open new instance of git bash you should be able to perform your git commands.

This worked for me, I was able to pull and push into my remote repo.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. And I solved it by changing the remote branch's path from `https://github.com/YourName/RepoName` to `git@github.com:YourName/RepoName.git` in the repo's settings of the client app.

Comment: You are trying to solve the problem using SSH link. I would prefer working with HTTPS and your answer can not help me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm constantly running into this problem.
Make sure you set git --config user.name "" and not your real name, which I've done a few times..

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers were working for me. In my case I needed access for a given organisation. So renewing the token was not enough, I also had to grant access for that particular organisation.

This is the complete process I had to go through to restore access to the repositories of my organisation:

1. Regenerate token (in my case I already had a token which had expired)
   [image]
2. Copy the token
3. Add permissions more my organisation:
   [image]
4. Use the token to access your repo, for example by doing:

   ```
   % git pull
   Username for 'https://github.com': YOUR_USER
   Password for 'https://YOUR_USER@github.com': PASTE_TOKEN
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I just disable the Two-factor authentication and try again. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably want to keep 2FA enabled for your account, you can set up a ssh key and that way you won't need to type your Github credentials every time you want to push work to Github.

You can find all the ssh setup steps in the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent). First, make sure you don't currently have any ssh keys (id_rsa.pub, etc.) with `$ ls -al ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by installing [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) and running `gh auth login`

See:
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git#github-cli

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sample-url.git
Cloning into 'Project'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/sample-url.git/'
```

I just `git init` first and then `git clone <clone-url>`

```
git init
git clone https://github.com/your-clone-Url
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Strange. It should not. All you did was to clone a repository inside another local repository. That should have no effect on the authentication needed by your `git clone` command.

Answer (score 1):

If someone faces this issue on VS Code then changing the git protocol setting to `ssh` will solve the purpose.
[image: git protocol vs code setting]

Answer (score 0):

## There is a issue on Windows using cmd-Greetings

There is a issue on Windows using cmd-Greetings who will not let you clone private repositories. Remove that cmd-greeting described in this documentation (keyword `Command Processor`):

[Known-Issues](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/development/docs/known-issues.md#authentication-errors-due-to-modified-registry-entries)

I can confirm that other clients like SourceTree, GitKraken, Tower and TortoiseGit affected to this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this might happen. In my case, none of the solutions worked.  In particular, `git pull origin master` did not ask me for my username and password.

I was on Windows with a github password recently changed.  I was using the credential manager to manage my password.  Here is what worked for me:

1. Confirm you are using the credential manager for git:

   git config --list
   …
   credential.helper=manager
2. Run a new command prompt as administrator
3. List all stored credential with `cmdkey /list` from `C:\WINDOWS\system32>`
4. Remove the github target with `cmdkey /delete:<target name>`.  In my case, the target name was `github.<companyname>.com`
5. Open a new prompt and run a git command.  You should get a popup asking for your usernmame and password.  After providing the new credentials, it won't ask you for it again.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this issue all I did to resolve it was to **Generate new token** from  my github dashboard and paste the following code in my terminal

$ git remote set-url origin https://your-github-username:your-github-token@github.com/your-github-username/your-github-repo.git

Answer (score 0):

after typing
`git pull origin (main or master)` 
it gave me to type my username and password

after this I tried to use pushing using
`git push origin main`

then it worked with the same approach it asked me to type my username then password I typed my generated token from GitHub then it started to push successfully

Answer (score 0):

My exact error was

```
Remote: Invalid username or password.
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
Authentication failed for <repo name>
```

after doing a git Pull from the Visual Studio UI.

### Solution

1. Open a command line window
2. Go to the root of the repo
3. `git pull`
4. Watch git output the changes it pulled!

A simple solution to a frustrating problem for Visual Studio users!

Answer (score 0):

For me the culprit was in `.git/config`, I had to remove these two lines:

```bash
[http "https://github.com/"]
        extraheader = AUTHORIZATION: basic <...>
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when doing a git push, and it is because of the 2FA mechanism.
If you already have generated the new token and you have git installed in your windows machine. You can just do a "git pull origin master" and the git UI will be launched, and you will be prompted to put the new token.
After this the token has now been updated, you can now perform your git push.

Answer (score -3):

This solution worked for me:

1. open Control Panel
2. Go to Credential Manager
3. Click Window Credentials
4. In Generic Credential section ,there would be git url, update username and password
5. Restart Git Bash and try for clone

Comment: This answer duplicates an existing answer which is not useful. When you have enough reputation (15, I believe) you can vote up answers that you find useful. Voting would be the correct response rather than adding this duplicate answer.