# Vscode : How to i change saved github username and password?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have repository on github i want to take a pull a branch in my local machine.

```
git pull 
git pull origin development
```

result in the following error

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'repolink.git'
```

currently using a win7 system, i tried changing it via control panel > credential manager didn't work.

Any other alternative?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297154/github-invalid-username-or-password

Comment: So, the other day i just restart my pc after removing credential from cred manager and it works, asked me to  save my username and password