# Not able to connect private github repository in apache ariflow helm chart in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am new working with Airflow and Kubernetes. I am trying to use apache Airflow in Kubernetes.

To deploy it I used this chart: https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/chart.

I want to upload my dags in my github repository so:

```yml
gitSync:
    enabled: true
    # git repo clone url
    # ssh examples ssh://git@github.com/apache/airflow.git
    # git@github.com:apache/airflow.git
    # https example: https://github.com/apache/airflow.git
    repo: https://github.com/mygithubrepository.git
    branch: master
    rev: HEAD
    root: "/git"
    dest: "repo"
    depth: 1
    # the number of consecutive failures allowed before aborting
    maxFailures: 0
    # subpath within the repo where dags are located
    # should be "" if dags are at repo root
    subPath: ""
```

Then I see that to use a private github repository I have to create a secret as is specified in the value.yml file:

```yml
# if your repo needs a user name password
    # you can load them to a k8s secret like the one below
    #   ---
    #   apiVersion: v1
    #   kind: Secret
    #   metadata:
    #     name: git-credentials
    #   data:
    #     GIT_SYNC_USERNAME: <base64_encoded_git_username>
    #     GIT_SYNC_PASSWORD: <base64_encoded_git_password>
    # and specify the name of the secret below
    #credentialsSecret: git-credentials
```

I am creating the secret:

```yml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  GIT_SYNC_USERNAME: bXluYW1l
  GIT_SYNC_PASSWORD: bXl0b2tlbg==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: git-credentials
  namespace: default
```

Then I use the secret name in the value.yml file:

```yml
repo: https://github.com/mygithubrepository.git
    branch: master
    rev: HEAD
    root: "/git"
    dest: "repo"
    depth: 1
    # the number of consecutive failures allowed before aborting
    maxFailures: 0
    # subpath within the repo where dags are located
    # should be "" if dags are at repo root
    subPath: ""
    # if your repo needs a user name password
    # you can load them to a k8s secret like the one below
    #   ---
    #   apiVersion: v1
    #   kind: Secret
    #   metadata:
    #     name: git-credentials
    #   data:
    #     GIT_SYNC_USERNAME: <base64_encoded_git_username>
    #     GIT_SYNC_PASSWORD: <base64_encoded_git_password>
    # and specify the name of the secret below
    credentialsSecret: git-credentials
```

but seems not bee working.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you are connecting to your github repo via `https`.

Try to use:

```
ssh://git@github.com/mygithubrepository.git
```

or simply

```
git@github.com/mygithubrepository.git
```

You can experience issues with connecting via `https` especially if you have two-factor authentication enabled on your github account. It's described more in detail in [this](https://medium.com/@ginnyfahs/github-error-authentication-failed-from-command-line-3a545bfd0ca8) article.

Also take a look at [VonC's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29297250/11714114) where he mentions:

> As noted in  [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101662/oliver)'s
> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919582/6309), an HTTPS URL
> would not use username/password if  [two-factor authentication
> (2FA)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa)
> is activated.
>
> In that case, the password should be a  [PAT (personal access
> token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication#using-two-factor-authentication-with-the-command-line)  as seen in "[Using a token on the command
> line](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line#using-a-token-on-the-command-line)".
>
> That applies only for HTTPS URLS, SSH is not affected by this
> limitation.

As well as at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21027728/11714114) provided by [rc0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155236/rc0r).

But as I said, simply using `ssh` instead of `https` should resolve your problem easily.

Comment: Agreed: using a token is the bast practice (instead of using your account password): https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token#using-a-token-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue. I was just about to use ssh instead, but then just persisted. How I got https to work (using a PAT) is:

Fill in your repo URL

```
repo: "https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git"
```

Add the name of your secret

```
httpSecret: "my-airflow-secret"
```

Fill in this part too

```
httpSecretUsernameKey: "your-username-key"
httpSecretPasswordKey: "your-PAT-key"
```

Now, the key is, when creating your base64 encoded strings to put in your secret, use:

```
echo -n "your-user-name" | base64
```

The -n means echo doesn't append a newline. After that It worked correctly.  I have many other applications that didn't mind base64 encoded strings without -n so I guess I just got a bit complacent. It took me a while to realise the issue though.