# git remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh

I'm getting this error from the terminal (ubuntu), although if I write `ssh -T git@github.com` I appear to be authenticated.
I've just added a new ssh key, and I have a global config file. I've already tried different solutions found online, with no luck.

Can anyone help please?

I've tried

```
`git push -u origin master` or `git push -u origin main`
```

and this is the output of git remote:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/loucat-dev/github-test.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/loucat-dev/github-test.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:loucat-dev/github-test.git (push)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `git remote -v` please, and indicate which remote you're pushing to?

Comment: just done it @bk2204, thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"`invalid username or password`" is not an error you would find with an SSH URL, but rather with an HTTPS one, as [I detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29297250/6309).

Try:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url git@github.com/<me>/<myrepo>
```

Then you can add, commit and try to push, to validate that the authentication does work when writing back to your remote GitHub repository.

Comment: Hi @VonC, I've tried that (adding "origin" before the repo url, as in your original post), but after I authenticate it still says Authentication Failed :(

Comment: @loucatdev The git remote you just added in your question is still showing an HTTPS URL, not an SSH one.

Comment: I've retried and after adding the remote with SSH, now the last entry is SSH (see the edited question). Still when I try to push it doesn't authenticate me

Comment: @loucatdev yes, because it will also use the https URL when pushing

Comment: Ok, I've removed the remote completely (including origin), then I added it back using the ssh url, and now it all works. Thanks!