# Pushing git commit from remote server through SSH: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh

I am connected through SSH to my machine at work, on which I am developing some code.
I have committed some changes, which I would now like to push, however, I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

AFAIK this issue occurs when the SSH keys for the git repo are not properly set up.

Thing is, I can push and pull no problems when I am physically at work using the computer.
The problem only occurs when I try to do so through a SSH connection.
Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VonC for leading me to the solution, which was re-generating the ssh keys. Unfortunately, simply renaming them to the default (id_rsa.pub and id_rsa) didn't work. This is more of a work-around than a solution, but it seems that in my case going in through ssh requires the git ssh keys to hold the default names.

Answer (score 1):

Through an SSH connection, you might not have the same environment variables than directly connected on your machine.

Check what, in your SSH session, $HOME refers to, and if you see your `$HOME/id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub` SSH private/public key files.

Then do a `ssh -Tv github.com` (replace github by the actual target server name) to see what is going on.

Comment: Riiiight, I actually called them bb_priv and bb_priv.pub respectively. I'll test if renaming the key files solves it

Comment: @MrSquid if those keys are called differently, check if you have an `~/.ssh/config` file, and if the ssh URL you are using to push (git remote -v) is `<configEntry>:<user>/<repo>`

Comment: No such file. Should I create one?

Comment: @MrSquid For testing, rename your keys first (if you don't already have `id_rsa(.pub)` files). If not, yes: follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274407/6309.