# How to switch from work Github account to Personal one?

Tags: git, github

I have two github accounts, one is personal and second one is work related. I am doing a 'command line' git commit to my personal repo, but it is still showing the 'work' account, throws  Permission to `personalaccount/sample.git` denied to `someworkaccount`. How do I switch the work account to personal one ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+accounts

Answer (score 0):

Check your `git config credential.helper` config: if it returns manager, that means the credentials (username/password) are cached.

Type `git credential-manager reject https://github.com`, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58361327/6309).
The next push will ask for your username/password again.

Comment: This can also be acheived with setting up SSH keys right ? One for Work Account, One for Personal ?

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz Yes, as I explain in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274407/6309. But I am answering here the HTTPS aspect, not SSH.

Comment: @VonC I  will try that and reply.

Comment: $ git credential.helper
git: 'credential.helper' is not a git command. See 'git --help' ..sorry if i am wrong ..

Comment: @soccerway Sorry, it was `git config credential.helper`. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have navigated to control panel > credential manager > remove windows credential for gitHub manually..Then while pushing my commits, it ask me to enter credentials...which worked out luckly...

Comment: So if I run the `git credential-manager reject https://github.com` will it remove all of the GitHub credentials of other GitHub accounts in one system ?

Comment: @soccerway There is only one credential associated to (and cached for) github.com at any given time. A reject will remove that one credential.