# PyCharm uses Git account from Credential Manager

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, github, pycharm

On my Windows 10 machine I need to have two Git accounts and I have no idea how to setup it. I have read about setting different values at different projects but my problem is slightly different. So I use Git in my Visual (Git extension for VS 2017 ; and my boss authenticated once ater cloning repo with his acc) and in PyCharm (build in version control).

When I want to push changes from Pycharm to my public Github repo I am getting error saying that my boss account is denied permission. And after deleting it from Credential Manager, I can push, pull everything.

After switching to Visual and doing something Git related, there is a entry added to Credential Manager.
And I am in loop. I need both things to work.

Answer (score 0):

> And I am in loop

Only if both remote repositories (the working one, and the public one) are both on GitHub.
Then the credential helper "manager" would only record *one* credential (username/password) for "`github.com`".

An alternative would be to use an SSH URL instead of an HTTPs one.
Then you could easily distinguish the credentials to use for each repository, as I mentioned in "[How to set up authentication for two separate GitHub accounts from same ssh client?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681936/6309)".