# How do I change the default directory in Git?

Tags: git

My problem is that my "Documents and Settings" folder is on a networked drive which is abysmally slow. Since this is where Git (and most programs) store all of their settings and stuff by default this ends up being a problem since even a simple "mkdir" can take upwards of 30 seconds. How do change Git to store all settings/repos in a diffent location?

Comment: What implementation of `git` is this? `msysgit`?

Comment: @notfed It's the default setup of Git-1.7 from http://git-scm.com/downloads. With the settings "Use Git Bash only" and "Use OpenSSH".

Comment: I apologize, I didn't realize they started a Windows link on `git`'s main website. But yes, it appears they provide `msysgit` as the implementation.

Comment: Similar question (with possibly correct answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454774/fix-msysgit-portable-home-location/3455231#3455231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store repos anywhere, so put them on the local disk.

To set up msys's`~` to be on local disk, answer posted to the proposed duplicate contains batch commands to set up stuff you need. Be careful to copy git global setting between old home and new home.

Comment: My only problem with this is that I can't just type "mkdir ~/SomeDir". I'm really lazy when it comes to things like that so I'd rather the default for everything be a particular spot on my hard drive rather than the networked drive.

Comment: I'm on mac tonight so I can't test right now, but you can try to change `$HOME` directory. GitExtensions has GUI for this I believe.

Comment: Thanks to you for the info and notfed for the link. I've been able to get my $HOME path changed.