# Git clone private repo, permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, repository, clone, private

I am trying to clone a private repository owned by another developer.  I do not have direct communication with this developer.  They sent me a theirusername-id_rsa.pub file and a theirusername-priv.key.ppk file.  I understand the ppk file is specific to to Putty ssh client.  Can someone provide me with steps on how to clone their repo?  I already have git configured with my own account and I think I have to add their ssh key to my ssh/config file or something, but I'm a bit of an ssh noob.

```
git clone git@github.com:theirusername/pro.git
Cloning into 'pro'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Edit: I was able to get access to the github repository and add myself as a collaborator.  Even after doing so I couldn't

```
git clone git@github.com:theirusername/pro.git
```

however

```
git clone https://github.com/theirusername/pro.git
```

did work.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby

Comment: Maybe you should try ssh:// scheme - if you have the keys in place try:

git clone ssh://username@host.xz/absolute/path/to/repo.git/

Comment: Why don't they just add you as a collaborator?

Comment: @Blender, I was given the files by a client.  I do not have direct communication with the developer/owner of the github repo.

Comment: Instead of cloning git@github.com version using the http:// version of that git repo.

Comment: @smichak The default scheme should be ssh.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> They sent me a theirusername-id_rsa.pub file and a theirusername-priv.key.ppk

First of all, tell them to *never* do this. The public/private keys are called like that for a reason. It’s against its point to have multiple instances (persons or computers) share the same key. You should use a separate key for every single one, to have a 1-to-1 association between them.

If they can’t add you as a collaborator (which would require a user account for yourself), then they should just add **your** key to their own profile. I’m emphasizing on “your key”, as **you** should generate it and send them only the public key. The private one should always remain secret to everybody else.

That being said, when you have a PPK, a PuTTY private key file, you have two options. First would be to use PuTTY’s *pageant* to load the key file and make Git use PuTTY’s *plink* as the SSH client. You can do that by setting the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to the path to `plink.exe`, e.g. `C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe`.

The second option would be to convert the PPK to an OpenSSH key file which the SSH client that comes with Git can use. You can do that by opening the PPK with PuTTYgen and choosing “Conversions/Export OpenSSH key”. You should save the file as `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\id_rsa` to make Git use it.

Comment: "never do this": I agree. I was answering the second part (which you do more precisely), but your reminder is useful. +1

Comment: Very important!!!!You should save the file as C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\id_rsa to make Git use it. "id_rsa". If you give any other name to your ssh file (which is what I was doing, IT WILL NOT WORK WITH GIT!!!)

Answer (score 4):

You need:

- to make sure you have environment variable `HOME` defined (if you do your git operations from a [git bash session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455231/6309), this should be defined for you even on Windows)
- to convert your ppk keys into id_rsa and id_rsa.pub: see "[How to I tell Git for Windows where to find my private RSA key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key)".
- define your config file or add your key to ssh agent, as described in "[Specify private SSH-key to use when executing shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby)".

Comment: And to be very sure that your client has legal permission to pass along his or her key and let you in if they are not the owner. Looks like trouble to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste below code in a bat file and execute it

echo y|"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -pw XXXX exit

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX : This is IP Address of your device.

XXX : This is password of your device