# Receiving error when try to clone a repository - git

Tags: git, heroku

I've created a heroku app and this is the git address :

```
git@heroku.com:sheltered-meadow-7151.git
```

But when I try to clone the repository I receive this error :

> $ git clone git@heroku.com:sheltered-meadow-7151.git Cloning into
>   'sheltered-meadow-7151'... Could not create directory
>   '/home/Adrian/.ssh'. The authenticity of host 'heroku.com
>   (50.19.85.156)' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is
>   8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad. Are you sure you want
>   to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Failed to add the host to the
>   list of known hosts (/home/Adrian/.ssh/known_hosts). Permission denied
>   (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Update :

Output of

```
$ ls -l ~/.ssh
```

is :

```
total 1
----------+ 1 Adrian None 405 Oct  1 23:25 known_hosts
```

My .ssh keys are located in `C:\Users\Adrian\.ssh` so is the above dir pointing at an incorrect location ?

Update 2 :

I've copied all keys into the ~/.ssh folder but receiving same error

Comment: You should have write permission on `.ssh`, is it so? Paste the output of `ls -l ~/.ssh` here if you're unsure.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni please see question update

Comment: What is the output of `ssh-add -l`?

Comment: @Kashyap $ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to set this up on a windows machine and these steps worked. (I'm using mingw32.exe as the bash emulator and not Putty)

```
$ ssh-agent
```

And this was the output of that command:

```
# SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-xxxxxxxx/agent.3840; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
# SSH_AGENT_PID=3572; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
# echo Agent pid 3572
```

Now, I don't know why the environment variables were not automatically set to the output. But they were not set. To fix it, run this command:

```
$ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-xxxxxxxx/agent.3840
```

And then run:

```
$ ssh-add ~/path/to/privatekey
```

That should do it.

---

Update: http://funkaoshi.com/blog/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent This blog post I found also verifies my claim that running `ssh-agent` does not set the environment variables and that these should be set manually.